# Count number of worksheets in Excel File

Tags: java, excel, excel-2003

How to count number of worksheets in a Microsoft Excel file using Java SE?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no *standard* class/library files in Java SE that interfaces with MS Excel. In [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), you can use `HSSFWorkbook.getNumberOfSheets()` method which returns you the number of worksheet from a workbook.

---

To open an Excel file and get `HSSFWorkbook`, do this:

```
String fileName = "C://Excel.xls";
POIFSFileSystem fileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(fileName));
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileSystem);
```

Comment: How do I open an Excel file as an HSSFWorkbook object?

Comment: 1) Do you have the Apache POI jar downloaded and setup in your project?

Comment: Yes. Jar downloaded, and path set.

Comment: So now, how do I open an Excel file as an HSSFWorkbook object?

Comment: @Sumon, I thought you'll consult your friendly Google, but since the laziness persists, I have updated my post to show you how.

Answer (score 2):

USE THE FOLLOWING CODE TO GET  number of worksheets

```
FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(FILE PATH));            

XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);         

System.out.println("number of sheet::"+ workbook.getNumberOfSheets());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `getNumberOfSheets()` in the `WritableWorkbook` class.

Take a look at these:

```
jxl.Workbook;
jxl.write.Label;
jxl.write.WritableSheet;
jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
```

http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html

Comment: Also provide a doc link like this one: http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html Not sure this is the latest doc but contains method `getNumberOfSheets()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public int getNumberOfSheets(File)throws Exception{
 FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
 HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
 int number_of_sheets =     workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
 return number_of_sheets
}
```

Above is a simple method to get the number of sheets in an xls workbook

Answer (score 0):

You can use [xlsx4j](http://docx4java.org)  to count. This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidFormatException, Docx4JException {
    SpreadsheetMLPackage spPackage = SpreadsheetMLPackage.load(new File("D:/MyFile.xlsx"));
    List<Sheet> sheetList = spPackage.getWorkbookPart().getJaxbElement().getSheets().getSheet();
    System.out.println("Number of worksheet: "+ sheetList.size());
    System.out.println("Sheet name: ");
    for (Sheet sheet : sheetList) {
        System.out.println(sheet.getName());
    }
```